# How to render a sprite 2 seconds after a collision

Tags: java, libgdx

I want to draw/render my sprite 2 seconds  after a collision.

How can I make it ?

If i do in that way the render add a new `ButtonOrange` immediately.

```
@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch batch)
{
    relation.add(new ButtonOrange(coordinates,text);
    relation.get(0).update();
    relation.get(0).draw(batch);

    if(relation.get(0).collission() == true)
        relation.remove(0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a temporary timer variable to store time elapsed since collision and if its greater than 2 second, draw that sprite.

```
boolean flag = false;
float time = 0; //timer for 2 sec

@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch batch)
{
    if(body.collision == true)   //just a dummy code to check for collision
      flag = true;               //set flag to true if collided

    if(flag == true)
    {
      //keep track how much time has elapsed
      time += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();     

      if(time > 2)           //if more than 2 sec
        sprite.draw(batch);       //draw sprite
    }

}
```