# How do I use a timer to create a 'get ready!' delay at the beginning of my game?

Tags: timer, libgdx, delay

So when a level of my game is created, the enum game state is made STATE.intro, and when in this state the game is instructed to do a 3 second countdown before changing the state to STATE.playing, after which you can actually start playing and the screen starts moving. This is to give the player 3 seconds to get ready between pressing the 'play' button and actually playing. Unfortunately, it only registers for the first two levels. It doesn't matter what level i start myself on, the 3rd level will not have this delay at the beginning and I have no idea why. To paint a better picture, here's some code from my render method:

```
  if(gameState == STATE.intro) {                //at the start of the level, wait 3 seconds for the player to get ready
                getReadyText.draw(batch, "GET READY!", centerX - (Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/10), screenCeiling-(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2));
                introDelay(); 
            }

 public void introDelay() {
    //creates a delay from when the level loads, and you start playing 

    if(intro) {
        intro = false;

        Timer.schedule(new Task() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                gameState = STATE.playing;
            }
        }, 3);      //3 seconds
    }

}
```

intro is a separate boolean set to true when the level is created. I use it to make sure the timer is created only once and not every frame that the state of the game is in 'intro' mode. Also note introDelay() is not inside render. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you are not resetting the state? By the way, i would advice [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32667282/how-to-render-a-sprite-2-seconds-after-a-collision/32667554#32667554) method instead of Timer to avoid any thread race conditions for delay.

Comment: but i want to draw the map during the delay so the player knows what to expect at the very start

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your code is going inside the if(intro){...} statement for the third time? In addition I'm agree with Kush and I would suggest to use a counter which is rising with deltaTime in each frame instead of Timer.schedule function. It would be like this

```
 public void render(float deltaTime) {
     stateTime += deltaTime;
     ...
     switch(gameState)
     {
          case State.STATE_INTRO:
               getReadyText.draw(batch, "GET READY!", centerX - (Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/10), screenCeiling-(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2));
               if(stateTime > 3) {
                   setState(State.STATE_PLAY);
               }
               break;
          case State.STATE_PLAY:
               //your code for playing state;
               break;
     }
}

public void setState(State state) {
    stateTime = 0;
    gameState = state;
}
```